# Why does this OrDone Channel Implementation receive twice from Done Channel?

Tags: go

Been reading through `Concurrency in Go` and it introduces a handy "or-done" channel.

TLDR; when you're working with a channel that you're not in control of (presumably from some other part of your system), the code can get a little ugly.

```
// Quite nice to read
for v := range myChan {
  ... Do Stuff
}

// Not so nice
loop:
for {
  select {
  case <- done:
    break loop
  case maybeVal, ok := <-myChan:
    if !ok {
      return
    }
    // Do something with maybeVal
  }
}
```

The book offers a way to simplify this with the OrDone channel.  Defined as follows.  What I don't understand is why, in the nested select, we need to again receive from <-done.

```
orDone := func(done, c <-chan interface{}) <-chan interface{} {
  valStream := make(chan interface{})
  go func() {
    defer close(valStream)
    for {
      select {
      case <- done:
        return
      case v, ok := <-c:
        if !ok {
          return
        }
        select {
        case valStream <- v:
        case <-done: // Why do we also need to receive on done here?
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return valStream
}
```

This allows you to go back to your original for loop, enhancing readability - like so:

```
for val := range orDone(done, myChan) {
  // Once again, do something
}
```

Comment: "Why do we also need to receive on done here?" Because `valStream <- v` blocks forever if the receiver loses interest.

Comment: that...was so painfully obvious after you pointed it out.  Thank you.

Comment: ...and so we have at least a way to clean up the helper goroutine launched from `orDone`  (by closing `done`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really just adding visibility to Peter's answer.

It's because valStream itself may block the send if whoever is receiving valStream loses interest.

Answer (score 2):

In a situation where you have received a value from channel `c` you enter into your nested `select{}`. At this point if we took out the second `<-done` you would have this;

```
select {
case valStream: <- v:
}
```

This will block indefinitely until a value is received from channel `v` even if the `done` channel is closed. By adding a nested check, we allow ourselves to exit the `select{}` at either point.

Answer (score 1):

An additional question, why is the body of that "case <-done:" empty?

```golang
orDone := func(done, c <-chan interface{}) <-chan interface{} {
  valStream := make(chan interface{})
  go func() {
    defer close(valStream)
    for {
      select {
      case <- done:
        return
      case v, ok := <-c:
        if !ok {
          return
        }
        select {
        case valStream <- v:
        case <-done: 
            return  // I think there should be a "return" here
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return valStream
}
```

Comment: There is no need to return in `second <-done`

if done channel is closed and the second `case <-done` read it, then
for loop will loop one more time, then this time the first `case <-done` will read the closed done channel